# How to expand to a normal vessel with ITK when I have a skeleton line and every radius for pixels?

Tags: itk

I did an thinning operation on vessels, and now I'm trying to reconstruct it.

How to expand them to normal vessels in ITK when I have a skeleton line and radius values for each pixel?

Comment: is the radius uniform or different at different pixels on the skeleton ?

Comment: The pixels are of different radius. I tried VesselTubeSpatialObject but it seems it could not include all organ vessels because it confused by ends and made lots of round-ups.

Comment: if your radius was uniform, you could use a fast marching filter on the skeleton & get the vessel tree right away. However since you have diff radii at each point it is challenging. You should post this on the itk lists too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DISCLAIMER: This could be slow, but since no other answer has been suggested, here you go.

Since your question does not indicate this, I'm assuming that you're talking about a 2D image, but the following approach can be extended for 3D too. This is how I'd go about it:

1. Create a blank image with zero filled pixel values
2. Create multiple instances of disk/sphere [ShapedNeighborhoodIterator](http://www.itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1ShapedNeighborhoodIterator.html) each having a different radius on the blank image (choose the most common radii from the vessel width histogram).
3. Visit each pixel in the binary skeleton image. When you come upon a white (vessel skeleton) pixel, recollect the vessel radius at that pixel.
4. If you already have a ShapedNeighborhoodIterator for that radius value, take the iterator to the pixel location in the blank image and fill up a disk/sphere of white pixels centered about that pixel. If you don't have a ShapedNeighborhoodIterator for that radius value, create one and do the same operation.

Once you finish iterating over the skeletonized image, you will have a reconstructed tree in the other image. Note that step 2 is optional, but will help you achieve faster computation.